# How to have 2 posting pages on a blog

Tags: posts, customization, pages, posting

It is possible to have 2 posting pages on a page? I have a static home page and I want to create 2 more pages for my blog which are "News" and "Recent Projects".

Answer (score 0):

You can create page templates for your post listings and tune them depending on your requirements.

Take a look at [this example](http://digwp.com/2013/01/display-blog-posts-on-page-with-navigation/) for the latest posts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a category page? See the docs [Category Templates « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)

> When a viewer clicks on a link to one of the Categories on your site,
>   he or she is taken to a page listing the Posts in that particular
>   Category in chronological order, from newest Posts at the top to
>   oldest at the bottom. There are many display choices, including
>   whether to display the complete post or post excerpts, and what
>   additional information to display (title, author, publish date, last
>   modified time, etc.). Each theme makes different choices, and you
>   might want to change them

Add a custom link to your menu for each category slug: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Try this to get rid of the category slug, too: [Wordpress Plugins » WP No Category Base](http://wordpresssupplies.com/wordpress-plugins/no-category-base/)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can. You have to create first new post types. You can do it in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_YourPostType' );

function register_cpt_YourPostType() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'YourPostType', 'your-post-type' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'YourPostType', 'your-post-type' ),
        ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'YourPostType', 'your-post-type' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'Your description',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'slug' => 'your-post-type',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'your-post-type', $args );
}

/**********************************************************************/
```

And then, use your desired post type in every template:

```
$type = 'your-post-type';
$args = array (
 'post_type' => $type,
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1
);
$temp = $wp_query; // assign ordinal query to temp variable for later use  
$wp_query = null;

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
if($wp_query->have_posts()) {   
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
            ...
```